# Latest Docker Desktop version 4.2 has no Settings Link for Shared Drive

Tags: sql-server, docker

In the settings of the earlier version 3 of Docker Desktop, there is a link on the page for Shared Drives.  I have version 4.2 on my desktop and it shows only the following:

```
General
Resources
Docker Engine
Experimental Features
Kubernetes
Software Updates
```

Is there a way to share without this feature in the Settings listing?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you have your `docker-compose.yml` as the starting point for your Docker container, all you have to do to mount a shared drive and to be able to use it from within your container, is to add a volume for your shared drive:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  your-service:
    image: '...'
    volumes:
      - shared-drive-1:/your_directory_within_container

volumes:
  shared-drive-1:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: "username=your username,password=your password"
      device: "//192.168.1.101/..."
```

Comment: Impressive.   I don't have it working just yet.  Is there a location that describes the docker-compose configuration parameters?   I can see, though it says I am at the latest version, that I am 3.7 and not 3.8    The version specific contest is version: "3.7" with double quotes (probably not significant).   Is there something else to know here?  Maybe it is possible to use a federated context that contains no user name and password.  Also probable is related to the use of a company laptop which hasn't yet gone to the next Windows 10 version.    Anything else you can assist with is appreciated